# a shell script to list files with date-1

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have some files like T24_STFBNK_CUSTOMER_**20181001**07553815383733380046446200.txt. The bold numbers `20181001` is the date of the file,I need a shell script to list the files which its date is yesterday only! how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `date` command:

```
date --date=yesterday +%Y%m%d
20181103
```

You can substitute it in a string with:

```
$ echo pre__"$(date --date=yesterday +%Y%m%d)"__post
pre__20181103__post
```

If you understand this, you can now use `ls` and globbing, adjusting the searched pattern as needed. Eg.:

```
$ ls *pre__"$(date --date=yesterday +%Y%m%d)"__post*
pre__20181103__post
```

This has listed the file `pre__20181103__post` present in the current directory.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply!
i understand you ! i have a folder that contains some files with this name! so i have to loop through this files and list the files with date of yesterday! how can i get the pattern 20181001?

Comment: @TarekSayed 1) You don't have to loop. Read more on globbing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming) 2) If you want to use a simple text like `20181001`, you don't have to produce it with any automatic tool. It is a valid string itself.

Comment: how about using ls to list all files in one file and after that i will use grep | TZ=aaa24 date +%Y%m%d to to find the files with yesterday's date! after that what should i do?

Comment: @TarekSayed It's a bad practice to operate on the output of `ls`. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead